# How to fix this PhpStorm, Docker and PhpUnit issue?

Tags: php, docker, phpstorm, phpunit

I have three docker containers:

- prefix-php-fpm
- prefix-mysql
- prefix-mysql-test

I have configured Docker, remote PHP interpreter and PhpUnit in PhpStorm.
But when i run tests which requires DB connection to the `prefix-mysql-test` container i receive error: `PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known`.
But when i run all my tests through container console (`docker-compose exec prefix-php-fpm bash`) - there is no errors and all tests pass.

What should i change in my PhpStorm configuration?

- [CLI interpreters settings screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6P5rX.png)
- [PHP settings screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UWZJZ.png)
- [Test frameworks settings screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t9vl1.png)